# Run program at startup Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, startup

I'm pretty new to some of these concepts so I hope you guys take it easy on me over this.

I want to run a program at start up in Ubuntu which I called Message.java. I did a little research and figured I could move Message.Class (someone told me to compile .java into a class first) into `/etc/init.d`. Then I used these commands:

```
sudo mv Message.class /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/Message.class 
sudo update-rc.d Message.class defaults
```

What I want is for a simple message dialog with "Hello World" to display at startup. So far, nothing happens. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Do I even have the right idea? (I'm just going off other posts). And if I'm completely wrong can someone point towards a good tutorial? Here's the code just in case:

```
public class Message {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        Component frame = null;
        //default title and icon
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Hello World"); 
        }
}
```

Comment: `init.d` != logging into your desktop environment

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, init.d is run on system startup.  System startup is not when you log into the desktop, but when the operating system has reached a certain point in the boot process.  init.d is typically used for running background processes and services.

Also, when you put in init.d has to be executable.  A .class file isn't executable.  You have to run a .class file by using the java command (eg. `java HelloWorld`).  You would need to make a bash script to start it if you wanted it to run at this point.

(These aren't criticisms, just things to try and understand about how the architecture works.  I didn't understand them when I started either.)

However since you want it to run when the user logs in you'll need to use another method.  Depending on what flavor of Ubuntu you have you'll need to do something different.  If it's the default and a recent version then you'll need to figure out how **Unity** run things on user login.  If it's a **Gnome** or **KDE** flavor you'll need to find out those respective desktop environments run things when a user logs in.

I'll assume you have Unity and see if I can find a good simple guide to set a 'program' (again you'll need to make a small file that run your `java` command) to run on user login.

**EDIT:**

[This guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) seems to be rather comprehensive on how to set a program to run on login.  You'll want to put the full path to your bash script in the 'command' box.

Comment: `java HelloWorld`, not `java HelloWorld.class`

Comment: Thanks Everyone. This was informative. I appreciate it.

Comment: @jlordo Thanks, I forgot about that.